# Importing shared Python Module in Dataflow (Apache Beam) job

Tags: python, dependencies, python-import, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm building out a series of data pipelines using Google Cloud's Dataflow tool.

This is my file structure:

```
-- dataflow_jobs
    |-- README.md
    |-- cleanse_export
    |   |-- __init__.py
    |   |-- run_cleanse_export.py
    |   |-- setup.py
    |   `-- src
    |       |-- __init__.py
    |       `-- cleanse_export.py
    |-- constants
    |   |-- __init__.py
    |   `-- constants.py
    `-- utilities
        |-- __init__.py
        `-- data_transform_functions.py
```

The idea is that `constants` and `utilities` should be shared libraries used by other (future) jobs under `dataflow_jobs`.

Following [this example](https://github.com/apache/beam/tree/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/complete/juliaset), I built out a `setup.py` file that looks like this:

```
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

setup(
    name="dataflow_job",
    version="0.0.1",
    install_requires=["scrubadub==2.0.0"],
    packages=find_packages()
)
```

In my main program (`cleanse_export.py`), I'm importing a couple of local packages:

```
import time
import uuid
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
import sys

sys.path.append("../")
from constants.constants import (
    DATAFLOW_RUNNER,
    PROJECT,
    REGION,
    SETUP_FILE,
)
from utilities.data_transform_functions import (
    cleanse_pii,
    _logging,
)
```

I keep getting a `ModuleNotFound` error:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utilities'`.

I'm trying to get `setup.py` to recognize and install my local python modules (`utilities` and `constants` on the worker machines when the job launches.

I tried adding

```
packages=find_packages() + 
packages=find_packages(where='../constants') + packages=find_packages(where='../utilities')
```

To my `setup.py`'s `packages` parameter, but I'm getting the same result.

Why isn't `setup.py` recognizing the modules in directories above it, and how can I get it to recognize these local modules in the current file structure?

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem and use/import the shared folder like separated packages, you can put the `setup.py` at the root of your project, example :

```
-- dataflow_jobs
    |-- setup.py
    |-- README.md
    |-- cleanse_export
    |   |-- __init__.py
    |   |-- run_cleanse_export.py
    |   `-- src
    |       |-- __init__.py
    |       `-- cleanse_export.py
    |-- constants
    |   |-- __init__.py
    |   `-- constants.py
    `-- utilities
        |-- __init__.py
        `-- data_transform_functions.py
```

Go inside the `dataflow_jobs` folder and launch your `Dataflow` job with a command that looks like :

```bash
cd dataflow_jobs

python -m cleanse_export.run_cleanse_export \
        --runner=DataflowRunner \
        --staging_location=gs://your_staging_bucket/staging/ \
        --region=europe-west1 \
        --setup_file=./setup.py \
        ....
```

In this case, your job will work correctly with the import you proposed initially in your question.

When you will create and move these folders in separate packages, the import will remain identical.

Comment: If you're using a venv, you'll want to filter its stuff out in `setup.py`:

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
   name="analytics_dataflow",
   version="0.2",
   install_requires=[],
   packages=setuptools.find_namespace_packages(exclude=["*venv*"]),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to use sys.path, try to get the correct path using Path(**file**).resolve() from pathlib.

Comment: This should be more of a comment

Comment: As a new member, I do not have enough reputation to add a comment...